# In Javascript, how can I find and parse out a 6 digit number?

Tags: javascript, regex

Let's say I have a string of text like:

"Hello, your work pin number is 931234.  Again, the number is 931234."

How do I parse out the *first* 6 digit number that I find? (in this case, 931234)

Comment: http://regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
var msg = "Hello, your work pin number is 931234. Again, the number is 931234";
(msg.match(/\d{6}/) || [false])[0]; // "931234"
```

if no 6-digit occurence is found then the statement will return `false`

Comment: +1, but note that this will give an error if there are no six-digit numbers. (Though perhaps that can't happen?)

Answer (score 3):

One way for exactly 6 digits;

```
var s = "Hello, your work pin number is 931234. Again, the number is 931234."

//start or not a digit, 6 digits, not a digit or end
result = s.match(/(^|[^\d])(\d{6})([^\d]|$)/);
if (result !== null)
  alert(result[2]);
```

Comment: Looks like the most correct answer to me. I'd use `\D` in the guard groups and make them non-capturing: `(?:^|\D)`

Answer (score 1):

```
var expr = /(\d{6})/;
var digits = expr.match(input)[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var text = "Hello, your work pin number is 931234. Again, the number is 931234.".replace(new RegExp("[^0-9]", 'g'), '');
alert(text.substring(0,6));
```

Comment: This alerts "Hello," - you need to use `/[^0-9]/g`.